# Hover in firefox doesn't work on nvd3 linechart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, nvd3.js

I'm using nvd3 to display a linechart in angularJs.

Everything works in Chrome, I can hover over the linchart et tooltip shows up. But when I try it in Firefox, hover does not seems to work. Marker doesn't show up like in chrome.

- Chrome: https://i.stack.imgur.com/soLL6.png
- Firefox: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h54TB.png

**directive**

```
directive('linechart', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function(rootScope, element, attrs){

            rootScope.$watch(attrs['data'], function(data){
                if(data){
                    nv.addGraph(function() {
                        var chart = nv.models.lineChart().width("500");

                        d3.select('linechart svg')
                        .datum(data)
                        .transition().duration(500)
                        .call(chart);

                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Sample data:**

```
[{
key: "Visiteurs",
values: [
    {x: 0, y: 0},
    {x: 1, y: 2},
    {x: 2, y: 4},
    ....
]
}]
```

I'm using 
nvd3: https://raw.github.com/novus/nvd3/master/nv.d3.min.js
css: https://raw.github.com/novus/nvd3/master/nv.d3.min.css

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line chart is internally based on nv scatter model, which by default changes its internal id every time data is reloaded. This breaks the tooltips in Firefox (but not in Chrome for some reason).

What worked for me was locking down the id of scatter chart:

```
nv.addGraph(function() {
  var chart = nv.models.lineChart().width("500");

  // Lock down id of scatter component
  chart.lines.scatter.id("some-id1");

  d3.select('linechart svg')
    .datum(data)
    .transition().duration(500)
    .call(chart);
});
```

Comment: I tried. But i got `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scatter' of undefined`

Comment: I had a typo in my answer. It should be `chart.lines.scatter` instead of `chart.line.scatter`.

Comment: @mlni do you know what the equivalent to this would be for linePlusBarChart?